# Restoring a duplicity backup with Dejà Dup from a different computer

Tags: backup, encryption, deja-dup

I'm making some scheduled encrypted backups from an Ubuntu Server to a remote computer, using duplicity.

What I'd like to do is to access that remote computer from a third machine, Ubuntu Desktop in this case, and being able to use the Dejà Dup GUI to restore backups.

I select

```
sftp://user@remotecomputer /home/user/backups
```

as source and it does find the backups and I can select the day to restore, but it complains about encryption and not having a secret key. Shouldn't it ask for the key then?

> GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
> ===== Begin GnuPG log =====
> gpg: AES256 encrypted data
> gpg: gcry_kdf_derive failed: Invalid data
> gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
> gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
> ===== End GnuPG log =====

Please don't suggest to use duplicity command line. I already know about it. I just want to know if there's something I can do to use the graphical front end.

Comment: Sounds like you should report a bug.

Comment: Reported: https://answers.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+question/698154